# How to convert Json buffer data to image in Node js

Tags: node.js, image, blob, buffer, png

{
"type": "Buffer",
"data": [
137,
80,
78,
71,
13,
10,
26,
10,
0,
0,
0,
13,
73,
72,
68,
82,
0,
0,
0,
32,
0,
0,
0,
32,
8,
6,
0,
0,
0,
115,
122,
122,
244,
0,
0,
0,
9,
112,
72,
89,
115,
0,
0,
11,
19,
0,
0,
11,
19,
1,
0,
154,
156,
24,
0,.....................continue......

Hello everyone!

I'm trying to make get request and display an image that stored in MySql database as blob type. 
The type's image is .png. 
I'm getting the above back from request, how can i solve this or maybe i did something wrong in database and now can't display the image?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello did you find any solution

Comment: No, but  I realise that this is not the best way, I mean to save images in data base. So no i didn't find any solution but als it's not a good option.

Comment: i have the next example view the next [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392241/how-convert-type-data-buffer-to-image-in-react-js/65392970?noredirect=1#comment115624365_65392970)

Comment: Thank you very much!