# How convert type data buffer to image in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, image, buffer

***Hello, i have next the image de type buffer, this data is one image, how can I convert my buffer data into an image***

*it shows me the following data when I make the request to the api*

[image]

Any suggestion

*The backend is made in node js sequelize MYSQL*.

*and the frontend in react js*

***I have next example***

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-christian-z4m1x?file=/src/LoadingData.js

***With this he retrieved the data from the MySQL database***
[image]

***In this way I register***

[image]

***and in this way the image is stored***

[image]

Comment: [This post was really helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react) It shows how to get it with url and binary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you need to convert your `Buffer` to `base64` string

```js
const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
```

Second, you need to use your string as `src` attribute for `img` tag

```
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64String}`} alt=""/>
```

I assume you are using `react`, so I recommend saving `base64String` in the component `state` and using it.

Comment: Hello, it generates a string that seems not to be base64, I put it in a web  page [link](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)  to check if it is base64 and it does not convert me to an image

Comment: it the next image => [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkqMN.png)

Comment: Try adding `data:image/png;base64,` to the beginning of the line

Comment: Hello i have example in codesandbox check in [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-christian-z4m1x?file=/src/LoadingData.js)

Comment: @MauricioCartagena, can I ask you to show the code on the backend part you are generating buffer? And type of file you are writing to buffer. Thanks

Comment: `const showQuestionShape = async ( req, res = response ) => { 

    const preguntaFormas = await PreguntasFormas.findAll();
 
     res.status( 200 ).json({
         ok:true,
         msg: 'List shape questions',
         preguntaFormas,
         
     });
};`

Comment: show  Mysql [saveDataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbldv.png)

Comment: No) just show `js` code how you create a new record in the table

Comment: [codeRegister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7J9R.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226263/discussion-between-mauricio-cartagena-and-xom9ikk).